# How to subscibe url and navigate without notify about changes in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable, router

I subscribe url and call method when component init and when user change url in browser using undo and redo operations. I want to change url in browser when user click button, but without run method in subscribe.
How can I do? Thank you. I use Angular 4

This is my code:

```
import { ParameterBase } from '../../form-data/interfaces/parameter.interface';
import { ParametersService } from './parameters.service';
import { ParameterRepositoryService } from '../shared/form-data-services/parameter-repository.service';
import { OffersPageService } from './offers-page.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'ofc-offers-page',
  templateUrl: './offers-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./offers-page.component.css']
})
export class OffersPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchForm: FormGroup = null;
  public showError: boolean = false;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: OffersPageService) {
  }

  public submit(): void {
    let url: Array<string> = this.service.ConvertFormToUrl(this.searchForm);
    this.router.navigate(url);
    this.service.getOffers();
    //change url without run subscribe method in ngOnInit
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(q => {
      //run when init component and user change url in browser Undo and Redo
      console.log('create form');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you can add metadata on url changes, aka `router.navigate(url, metadata)` or something like that.

Comment: Then, in `ngOnInit`, you'd do: `this.activatedRoute.url.filter(route => route.metadata.ignoreThis).subscribe(...)`.

Comment: I'm just guessing, this is what I would try to do.